# Which of the following statements are true? 4

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, metric-spaces

Which of the following statements are true?

a. There exists a continuous function $f : \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 2x^2 + 3y^2 =1\} \to \mathbb{R}$
which is one-to-one.

b. There exists a continuous function $f :( − 1, 1) \to ( − 1, 1]$ which is one-to-one and onto.

c. There exists a continuous function $f : \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : y^2  = 4x\} \to \mathbb{R}$
which is one-to-one.

My attempt:

```
        option a)  is true by Brouwer's fixed-point theorem

        option b)  is false because (0,1) and (0,1] are not homeomorphic.

        option c)  i don't know
```

Is my answer is correct or not ..  Could anyone tell me the solution?

Comment: I would not accept b) as an answer as I would need you to tell me *why* (0,1) and (0,1] are not homeomorphic.  Number 1) the domain is an ellipse.  Is it possible to have a one to one continuous function from an elipse?  if (x,y) is clockwise from (u,v) and f(x,y) > f(u,v) what does that tell you about the rest of the points?

Comment: In general a continuous bijection need not be a homeomorphism.

Comment: can u give me counter example @ danielWainfleet

Answer (score 1):

a) Note that the set is homeomorphic to a circle. If $f$ is a function to the reals from a circle, consider $f(x) - f(-x)$ and use the intermediate value theorem.

b) is false for another reason: at what point does the function assume the value $1$? Find a contradiction with injectivity.

c) Have you drawn it? It's a sideways parabola, can we see this as line, topologically?

Comment: that mean option a) is not one -one  but according  to  Brouwer's fixed-point theorem  it has one fixed point  ,,,because ellipse is convex ,compact and bounded..so option a)  must be one one...@ henno Brandsma

Comment: Pliz explain me in detail  of option C)...as i have drawn parabola ,,,,,how can i see this as a line @ henno Brandsma

Comment: @lomberlego Brouwer does not apply: your set is not convex and the function doesn't map such a set to itself.

Comment: As to c): map points with $y>0$ to reals $<0$ and with $y < 0$ to reals with $x>0$...

Comment: yes im getting option a),,,,,,,but for  option c)  here domain y^2 = 4x that mean  y =2√x,,,,,if y >0  that mean x must be >0....how it is possible that  real < 0,,,,and if y < 0 that mean x must negative ,,then y become a complex number,,,how it is possible to real x >0 ,,,,,can u  elaborate once again ? @ henno Brandsma

Comment: Actually $y = \pm 2 \sqrt{x}$, e.g. $(1,2)$ and $(1,-2)$ are both in your set. @lomberlego

Comment: okk,,,i m getting now ,,,thanks a lot @ Henno Brandsma,,,,May god bless u for kind help...

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Why do part (a) is false? Ellipse is homeomorphic to Circle and circle is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$[Via steriographic projection]. A homeomorphism is a bijective map. why do (a) fail to be one-one?. Please, can you explain? How do I find counter example for (b)?. i could solve (c). Please help me.

Comment: @N.Maneesh circle is certainly not homeomorphic to reals! Borsuk-Ulam implies non-injectivity.

Comment: Ok. I understood, It was not circle , circle without one point. Thank you.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma   For (b) part, I assumed that $\exists$ a continuous surjection from $(-1,1)$ on to $(-1,1]$. I am not able to proceed further. If it would be $[-1,1]$, I could prove either using Bolzano Weirstrauss Theorem or IVT to get a contradiction. Here, I am helpless. Please help me.

Comment: @N.Maneesh suppose that $p \in (-1,1)$ exists with $f(p)=1$. Look at the IVT for points around $p$.

Comment: How does it help me? $f(p)=1$ considering two interval $(-1,p] $ or $[p,1)$. $f(1)<f(p)$, $\implies$ $\exists$ $x\in (p,1)$ such that $f(1)<f(x)<f(p)$. similarly other case $\exists$ $y \in$ $ (-1,p]$ such that $f(-1)<f(y)<f(p)$. How does it contradict my assumption?

Comment: @N.Maneesh both $f[[x,p]$ and $f[[p,x’]]$ are of the form $[a,1]$. So they have a common point, contradicting injectivity.